# Best way for implement rules in a android chatapp

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm developing a chat application (android + PHP) and I have the following mysql database:
TABLE User: username (UNIQUE), psw, email (PK), location, user_id (unique), name

TABLE chat_user: id_chat_user, user_id1, user_id2

TABLE chat: id_chat (PK), id_chat_user, user_id, message, timestamp

User_id is generated with the php uuid function and then encrypted in md5. 
Now I should handle the roles to make sure that a user needs to read only his chats.
What method can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. To show a logged in user his all chats:

   `SELECT * FROM chat_user WHERE user_id1 = loggedInUserId OR user_id2 = loggedInUserId LIMIT 10;`
   where `loggedInUserId` is id of the logged in user.
2. To show a logged in user all messages from one of his chats

   `SELECT t2.* FROM chat t1 JOIN chat_user t2 ON (t1.id_chat_user = t2.id_chat_user) WHERE (t1.user_id1 = loggedInUserId OR t2.user_id2 = loggedInUserId) AND t2.id_chat = chat_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 100;`
   where `loggedInUserId` is id of the logged in user and `chat_id` is the select chat's id.

Comment: Thanks. But this method with an uid is secure? An user can read a chat of another user?

Comment: The queries that I wrote only allows a user to read chats that he's involved in. The uuid isn't required here, since queries return the chats of that user only.

Comment: Yes, but loggedInUserId is uuis that i generate with the function in PHP? This method is correct in a chatapp?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "this method". The queries I wrote above will apply to any application where a user wants to read only the chats that he's directly involved in.

Comment: Do you have any specific concern with this method?

Comment: What I would like to know is whether the database structure is correct

Comment: I just want to know what's the use of the `user_id` column in the `chat` table. Other than that, the structure looks good.

Comment: user_id is an user_id that i generate with a uniqid PHP function. I do this because otherwise everyone could read anyone's chat through the username.

Comment: I don't think you went through the queries I wrote for you above. I did read that user's chat without the use of the `user_id` column.

Comment: In my android app, I make a request to the server through a link. Sending the parameters via POST. If a user sees the code of my app then he may know that chats can be viewed through the username. No?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144003/discussion-between-gaganshera-and-raffaele-darco).